# displaying json strings from controller in view over ajax in asp.net core 2 MVC

Tags: c#, json, model-view-controller

Im calling an ajax function in a modal when I press a BTN which calls a Controller action and passes a parameter to controller. I now want to return strings as a Json back to the view and display them in the same Modal. Weirdly it worked on my laptop with dependency "System.Web.MVC" but doesnt seem to work in "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc". When returning the Jsons I fill the inputs in the modal with those json strings but on the PC with asp.net core the Inputs just stay empty where on the laptop they get filled.

Controller return type

```
       return Json(new { Nachname, Vorname, UserName });
```

Ajax

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnGet").click(function () {
        $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Action("getName", "Home")",
                data: {
                    UserName: $("#txtName").val()
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#infos').show();
                    $('#txtName').addClass("form-control is-valid");
                    $('#InputFirstName').val(result.Vorname);
                    $('#InputLastName').val(result.Nachname);
                    $('#InputFirstName').show();
                    $('#InputLastName').show();
                    $('#labelInfo').show();
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });

    });
});

`
```

Comment: Have you looked in the browser console to see if there are any errors? Also if you do `console.log(result);` what's displayed in the console?

Comment: For Core MVC you should try this: `return new JsonResult(new { Nachname, Vorname, UserName });`, because `ControllerBase` doesn't have `Json` method.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I tried it but seem to have the same issue still. Would I have to change something in the Ajax?

Comment: @Izzy yes I tried that. I get the right strings ect in the console.log. Just doesnt get displayed in the Modal

Comment: @MischaMorf Can you update the question and include the string that is displayed in the console please.

Comment: Can you try `$('#InputFirstName').val(result.vorname);` as your string is `vorname` and not `Vorname`.

Comment: I think I might have found why its not working but I dont know how to solve it. It gets the result in general and displays all the strings but when I return the result.Vorname in console it sais undefined.

Comment: @MischaMorf It will be undefined because it should be `result.vorname` not `result.Vorname`.

Comment: @Izzy yessss worked thanks man.

Comment: @MischaMorf Glad I could help. I have also made it as an answer so you can accept it as it might help future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, your string which is returned to is:

```
{nachname: "Morf", vorname: "Mischa", userName: "mrfmi"}
```

And you're using it as:

```
$('#InputFirstName').val(result.Vorname);
```

Here `result.Vorname` will be undefined so you need to change it as follows:

```
$('#InputFirstName').val(result.vorname);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be a missing parameter in your AJAX call?

Try adding:

```
dataType: "json"
```

to your parameters.

Comment: Thats the string I get when I console.log(result)

{nachname: "Morf", vorname: "Mischa", userName: "mrfmi"}

Comment: didnt work. Didnt have it in ajax but adding didnt help